# PHP unserialize serialized data

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I have a problem with unserializing serialized data.

The data is serialized and saved in the database.

This data contains a uploaded .csv url that I want to give back to fgetcsv.

fgetcsv expects a array and now a string is given, so I need to unserialize the data but this gives me errors.

I found this online http://davidwalsh.name/php-serialize-unserialize-issues but this doesn't seem to work. So I hope somebody can tell me where I go wrong:

Here is the error:

```
Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes in /xxx/public_html/multi-csv-upload.php on line 163
```

I found that this means that there are certain characters in the serialized data that makes the file corrupt after unserialization `(",',:,;)`

Line 163:

```
jj_readcsv(unserialize ($value[0]),true);` // this reads the url of the uploaded csv and tries to open it.
```

Here is the code that makes the data serialized:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'mcu_csv', serialize($mcu_csv));
```

This is WordPress

Here is the output of:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(unserialize($value));
echo '</pre>';
```

`Array
(
    [0] => http://www.domain.country/xxx/uploads/2014/09/test5.csv
)`

The way I see it there shouldn't be anything wrong here.

Anybody some idea's how I can unserialize this so I can use it?
Here is what I did sofar...

```
public function render_meta_box_content($post)
{

    // Add an nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field('mcu_inner_custom_box', 'mcu_inner_custom_box_nonce');

    // Use get_post_meta to retrieve an existing value from the database.
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mcu_images', true);

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r(unserialize($value));
    echo '</pre>';

    ob_start();
    jj_readcsv(unserialize ($value[0]),true);
    $link = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $editor_id = 'my_uploaded_csv';

    wp_editor( $link, $editor_id );




    $metabox_content = '<div id="mcu_images"></div><input type="button" onClick="addRow()" value="Voeg CSV toe" class="button" />';
    echo $metabox_content;

    $images = unserialize($value);

    $script = "<script>
        itemsCount= 0;";
    if (!empty($images))
    {
        foreach ($images as $image)
        {
            $script.="addRow('{$image}');";
        }
    }
    $script .="</script>";
    echo $script;
}

function enqueue_scripts($hook)
{
    if ('post.php' != $hook && 'post-edit.php' != $hook && 'post-new.php' != $hook)
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script('mcu_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'mcu_script.js', array('jquery'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to access the first element of the serialized string:

```
jj_readcsv(unserialize ($value[0]),true);
```

As strings are essentially arrays of chars, you are trying to unserialize the 1st char of the serialized string.

You need to unserialize 1st then access the array element:

```
//php 5.4+
jj_readcsv(unserialize ($value)[0],true);
//php < 5.4

$unserialized = unserialize ($value);
jj_readcsv($unserialized[0],true);
```

Alternatively, if there is only ever one element, dont store an array in the 1st place, just save the url string, which doesnt need to be serialized:

```
//save
update_post_meta($post_id, 'mcu_csv', $mcu_csv[0]);
//access
jj_readcsv($value, true);
```

Comment: Thank you. For explaining and it worked. FYI the array will be filled with more csv urls to files.

Comment: @Interactive Glad i could help. And yes i expected there was a reason for using arrays, but added the later code just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Data: a:4:{i:0;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":10:{s:10:"�*�_mapper";N;s:10:"�*�_answer";s:16:"tetsing answer a";s:8:"�*�_html";b:0;s:10:"�*�_points";i:1;s:11:"�*�_correct";b:1;s:14:"�*�_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"�*�_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"�*�_graded";b:0;s:22:"�*�_gradingProgression";s:15:"not-graded}}

```
<td>
<?php
$ser = $quiz_name->answer_data;
$ser = str_replace("\0*\0_", 'key_', $ser);
$un = unserialize($ser);
$un = json_decode(json_encode($un), true);
$answers = array_column($un, 'key_answer');
foreach ($un as $row) {
    echo '<li>' . $answers[] = $row['key_answer'] . '</p><br>';
}
?>
```